Puppeteer package not working on Flutter web
I'm working on a project which involves web scraping using puppeteer package with Flutter. I'm using puppeteer: ^3.6.0
My "flutter doctor" output is:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4460], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.7.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

I tried using it on a flutter windows app and it works fine, but when I try to use it on a webapp it gives me an error. The error happens when I try to launch puppeteer using the command:
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch(headless: true);

The error looks like this:
DartError: Unsupported operation: Platform._environment
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/io_patch.dart 279:5                   _environment
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform_impl.dart 83:17                                          get environment
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 177:59                                              get environment
packages/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart 299:71                                      defaultArgs
packages/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart 135:28                                      launch
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart 113:25                                      launch
packages/app_treni/Methods/GetTravelSolutions.dart 16:33                          getTravelSolutions
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/app_treni/Methods/GetTravelSolutions.dart 11:27                          getTravelSolutions
packages/app_treni/Pages/GoHome.dart 20:31                                        getSolutions
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/app_treni/Pages/GoHome.dart 18:20                                        getSolutions
packages/app_treni/Pages/GoHome.dart 32:5                                         initState
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5602:55                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6736:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5496:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5634:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5187:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5625:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5447:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4326:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3837:18                               updateChild


You scraping a web page? Puppeteer is a Node.js program?

https://github.com/xvrh/puppeteer-dart/issues/338
